# Can't install Ubuntu on Fujitsu Siemens M52212

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb, iso

Please help me to install Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.10 on Fujitsu Siemens M52212. I tried to do it by downloading ISO files (ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso and ubuntu-13.10-desktop-i386.iso) from the official website.

Then I burned the first one into a DVD. Installation began (the logo appeared) and failed with the black screen and inactivity of all drives. So I turned the laptop off. I decided to check the checksums of my ISO files. They were identical to the ones from the UbuntuHashes pages.

I tried to make a bootable Ubuntu flash drive using [this](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) and [that](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/) creator. Using two different USB drives and two different computers (running Windows 7 and Windows 8) in most of possible combinations. Each time I tried to install Ubuntu on the laptop, and the installation failed in the same way as with the DVD. And after installations I rerun the laptop and checked my USB for errors. And it found:

```
Check finished: errors found in 1 files.
```

Then I made the same check on another laptop, and it returned the same error. The same effect is if I try to load or check for errors on the DVD.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just find out that for `ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso` during boot time for some reason brightness decrees to **0** - just increase brightness by keyboard and you should be good to go.

Hopefully that helps